# Password Change With Command Line On NetBSD

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, password, netbsd

How can I change root password with one line command on NetBSD?
On FreeBSD, it's something like this

```
echo "password" | pw mod user root -h 0 ;
```

Comment: This could be the way of doing it:http://mail-index.netbsd.org/netbsd-users/2002/08/03/0005.html

Comment: one more way: using `passwd` and [tag:expect] (general-purpose input supplier for interactive [tag:cli] applications written in [tag:tcl])

Answer (score 4):

NetBSD does not support the `pw` command in its default install. You can:

1. Compile the `pw` command for NetBSD and install it on your systems
2. Write a utility that performs the equivalent functionality
3. Update the password by manipulating the shadow file directly

---

Note that depending on your script you should *probably* be using `-H` (and supplying an appropriately-encrypted password) instead of `-h`.
Passing unencrypted passwords around the system (especially if you're doing something like `echo "password"`) is a Bad Idea as it can result in exposing your password to any logged in user (or service).

Answer (score 1):

Use `usermod` with `-p` switch.  It's included with base system, no need to build `pw`.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered a similar use-case: automatically creating demo users with awful passswords, bypassing all password policies.  Without further ado, here's a nasty-but-works hack based on the mailing list suggestion:

### Bourn shell *function*

```
# example: set_password_insecure sybil magic
# $1: username
# $2: password
set_password_insecure() {
  if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo 'Missing username' >&2
    return 1
  fi
  ( PASSWORD_HASH="$(/usr/bin/pwhash "$2" | /usr/bin/sed 's@[\\$/]@\\&@g')"
   /usr/bin/env EDITOR="in_place_sed() { /usr/bin/sed \"\$1\" \"\$2\" > \"\$2.bak.\$\$\" && /bin/mv \"\$2.bak.\$\$\" \"\$2\"  ;}; in_place_sed 's/^$1:[^:]*:/$1:$PASSWORD_HASH:/' " \
     /usr/sbin/vipw
  )
}
```

### Bourn shell *command*

```
( USERNAME='mallory' PASSWORD='sex'; \
  PASSWORD_HASH="$(/usr/bin/pwhash "$PASSWORD" | /usr/bin/sed 's@[\\$/]@\\&@g')"
  /usr/bin/env EDITOR="in_place_sed() { /usr/bin/sed \"\$1\" \"\$2\" > \"\$2.bak.\$\$\" && /bin/mv \"\$2.bak.\$\$\" \"\$2\"  ;}; in_place_sed 's/^$USERNAME:[^:]*:/$USERNAME:$PASSWORD_HASH:/' " \
    /usr/sbin/vipw )
```

1. Works on both `sh` and `bash` (with `shells/bash` installed), and probably `zsh` too (untested).
2. Assume running as root, if not add `sudo` (with `security/sudo` installed) or `su - root -c` before `/usr/bin/env`.
3. `sed`/`mv` hack is due to `EDITOR` limitations + NetBSD's `sed` + requirement of no other dependencies / unnecessary temporaries / environment pollution.